# A comment script for managing new users

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderation, new-users

Since Lion's release we have gotten a lot of new users that are posting answers and sometimes questions without really understanding how the Stack Exchange format works. I am qualifying new users as anyone with a 100 (one hundred) or less reputation, but typically they only have 1 (one) point.

I have been collecting for the past couple of days a script for comments that I post before I manage their answer or question. I don't like closing or deleting questions and answers, but I like to offer an explanation before I do so. I have a standard intro and response (in italics below), and then I tack on the appropriate explanation. Some of these are my own and some I have picked up from other users...

- *Welcome to the community. Ask Different is not like other forums. Responses to questions must actually attempt to answer it.*

  - Comments like this should propel the general conversation forward

    - , and not just simply rant.
  - If you have a question, you should post your own instead of steering the thread away from the original. Please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button.
  - If you have sufficient reputation, you may upvote this question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

I deal with a number of new users over at GD.SE, and I have found this script has made my time moderating more efficient and consistent so I can get back to the real fun of actually answering questions. This really isn't a question as so much as posting a general resource so that others may add to it.

Comment: Is this related to the existing pro-forma comments script?

http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/pro-forma-comments

Comment: I had no idea that existed. That is *way* better.